# Check if editbox is active (and evaluate WindowKeyPressFcn only if its not) in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I would like to be able to test whether given **edit box** (`uicontrol` with `'style'` set to `'edit'`) is being **used** at the moment (whether the cursor is inside that box / the edit box has focus).

Unfortunatelly the `'Selected'` property of the editbox seems to be `'off'` all the time and it's use is discouraged by *MathWorks*

I am open to Java solutions (but I have not tried any yet).

### Background

My broader goal is to activate specific functions in response to keys pressed by the user (keyboard shortcuts) but only if the user is not typing these letters into an edit box.

I evaluate keyboard shortcuts with `'WindowKeyPressFcn'` callback. I thought about using editbox's `'KeyPressFcn'` callback to block `'WindowKeyPressFcn'` (by passing something through `setappdata` or `'UserData'`) but it seems that `'WindowKeyPressFcn'` is always evaluated first.

So now I'm trying to detect whether the editbox is in use some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MATLAB uicontrols have underlying Java Swing GUI controls, I can think of two "Java solutions":

1. [Associate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html#f16-1001315) a `FocusGainedCallback` with the Java object of editbox (using FindJObj - see below) (and possibly other UI elements), and update some handle \ persistent \ global variable from this function to hold the currently focused object handle. This type of callback is mentioned in an [UndocumentMatlab article on `uicontrol` callbacks](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uicontrol-callbacks).
2. You should be able to use Java's`isFocusOwner()` method on the underlying java object of your editbox (this method is mentioned in the [Java documentation of the focus subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#api)).

Note: the simplest way to get the java object is using the utility [`FindJObj`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) that is briefly described [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/findjobj-find-underlying-java-object/).

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out tomorrow. As far as I understand - the first solution also relies on Java object callbacks; `FocusGainedCallback` as well as `FocusLostCallback` are not available at the classic matlab uicontrol level.

Comment: I think you're right. Initially I wanted to suggest 'ButtonDownFcn', but then I noticed this (more suitable) alternative and didn't change the wording...

Comment: It works, thanks. :) But the first solution (the one I used) also requires getting java object handle with `FindJObj`. Would be nice if you edited your answer just a little bit to reflect that :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, much simpler method, would be to use the `WindowKeyReleaseFcn` callback of the GUI figure. This gets fired after the release of the keystroke, hence it gets executed after the `gco` gets the updated value of the currently focused uicontrol. The following check in the beginning of the `WindowKeyReleaseFcn` can determine if the keystroke comes from the **edit box**:

```
function figure1_WindowKeyReleaseFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% gco is already updated by the time we are here to reflect the uicontrol
% which is in focus

if isequal(gco, handles.hEditBox) % Keystroke comes from the edit box
    return
end

% Keystroke does not come from the edit box -- Do something here...
```